# Suddenly rails scaffold delete/destroy method is not working for any rails app(old,newly created)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ubuntu 14.04(on windows 7), rails 3.2.7, ruby 1.9.3. Before today everything is working fine. But suddenly today rails scaffold delete/destroy method is not working(old,new app). When I click to to destroy link it goes to show method and show the data.

Comment: we can't help you with this much information...

Comment: Do you have JavaScript enabled in the browser? Scaffold adds some client-side confirmation.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is enabled in my browser.@ViniciusPinto

Comment: What do your logs say when you click to destroy it? (the output when you run `rails server`) They should tell you whether it's a GET or DELETE request, the path that came in, the controller action that it routed to, params, etc. If you want to understand what's happening with your system, you need to learn to elicit feedback from it. This is a pretty good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

In application.js file make sure u have included

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

and in layouts -> application.html.erb add

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery_ujs" %>
```

It worked for me. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only add in application.js file make sure u have included

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs

Thats ok, destroy is run